# Does iMovie prevents going to sleep?

Tags: sleep, imac, imovie

I've started making a movie in iMovie project (which takes about 3 hours).

In System Preferences, i've seen the option to shedule, but leaved it disabled.

Also in System Preferences, i've set the 30 minutes of Idle mode to put my iMac to sleep.

When i woke up, the movie was ready, but iMac was awake (whole night).

The question is:

What exactly the Idle mode is, which keeps sleep timer running and puts the Mac to sleep ?

My Mac was in Idle, because after making movie it stayed whole night without doing anything ... (no CPU and disk usage, no downloads etc.)

Maybe, iMovies explicitly keeps iMac awake ?

Answer (score 1):

Imovie keeps the mac awake so it  can export, the idle mode is if the computer is unattended or not running video like quicktime.